# How to do analysis with PSU, Stratum , and multiple weights in R?

Tags: r

I have found in R "WeMix" packages contain the option of multiple weights but not PSU (primary sampling unit) and Stratum. Are there any packages in R which contains PSU, Stratum and Multiple weights?

Comment: Still, I didn't get any answer. Is there anyone who can give the answer?